# Adjectival clause construction

Tags: subordinate-clauses, antecedents

> 1. My brother brought the bread from India that you have eaten.
> 2. You have eaten the bread that my brother brought from India.

Is the that antecedent of the bread above in both sentence or there is some difference?

Comment: Is your concern that the antecedent of "which" could be "India", so the meaning is that someone has eaten India?!

Comment: Which is refer to bread